# How can I partition my ubuntu hard drive

Tags: 12.04

How can I partition my ubuntu hard drive.Im usıng linux ubuntu server and ım trying to partion into two .can you help me how to do this.still new to ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using fdisk utility. Here is a tutorial which I think might be helpful.
http://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/